# A codeblock after a list doesn't render correctly

Tags: discussion, formatting

Perhaps this is a known issue. You can't put a codeblock directly after a list, even separated with line breaks.  It came up in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/289857/38335), where I finally just added a colon between the list and codeblock so that it would look right.

Here's a list:

1. First line
2. Second line

   This should be a code block, check the markdown!

(there needs to be at least one normal character in this line, or the next codeblock won't render either. Line breaks don't do it)

```
This is also a codeblock
```

---

**Edit:**

I see that this has been discussed on meta.stackexchange.com; [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34292) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327) are two examples.  I don't see anything indicating that this behaviour will change.

But there are some good workarounds in those answers.  My preference is to use

```
<b></b>
```

or a blank html comment

```
<!-- -->
```

as a separator.

Comment: Interesting - have you seen if this has been reported on meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: No, I haven't looked, sorry. It'll be about an hour before I can search around :)

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to put a horizontal rule (a line with just `---` on it in Markdown) right before a code block, as a separator.

Comment: @W5VO It turns out that is has been discussed on meta.stackexchange.com. I've included info in my post and also removed the [bug] tag. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @DaveTweed. I was editing my question as you posted your answer.  I like the horizontal rule solution, and there were additional workarounds that I mentioned in my edit. Take care!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that Markdown considers any indented line to be part of the previous list item; this is a feature, not a bug. It gets indented to match the list indentation, but it doesn't get rendered in code font. A horizontal rule can fix this, and probably looks better than other options:

1. List item

   Second paragraph for list item #1
2. List item

   Second paragraph of list item #2

---

```
Code block
```

In Markdown, the horizontal rule is a blank line followed by a line containing just `---`.

---

Nested lists:

- Top item A

  1. 2nd-level item
  2. 2nd-level item

     text for 2nd level requires 5 spaces of indentation

  more text for 1st level
- Top item B

---

In any case, it's definitely quirky!